# How can I trap an event unhandled exception in debug mode with an add in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to develop a VS2012 add-in with this simple behaviour:

When I'm in debug mode in any program like console application or a Windows forms program, I would like to **trap the event "unhandled exception" spawned by Visual Studio** and do something like log into file or similar.

Any suggestion? Documentation? Is it possible?

Thanks :)

Here my simple code... into the Connect method I put a console.writeline but nothing happens

```
public Connect()
        {


            _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnExceptionNotHandled += DebuggerEvents_OnExceptionNotHandled;
            _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnExceptionThrown += DebuggerEvents_OnExceptionThrown;
            _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
        }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.debuggereventsclass.onexceptionnothandled.aspx

Comment: tanks for ur reply i added a snippet code of my implementation. To test it a run my addin in debug mode and in the new instance of visual studio i make simple program that spown a division by zero exception. But nothing happens in the output consolle. What's wrong?